# Salvar configurações do aplicativo

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Existe algo que eu possa fazer para salvar configurações do meu aplicativo sem precisar criar uma base de dados, para quando o aplicativo for fechado e depois reaberto ele continuar com as configurações que foram gravadas anteriormente?

Comment: Se uma das respostas resolveu o seu problema, você pode escolher a que melhor resolveu e aceitá-la, veja [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aqui tem o que tu precisa: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage?hl=pt-BR

Para obter um objeto `SharedPreferences` para o aplicativo, use um destes dois métodos:

- `getSharedPreferences()` — use esse método se precisar de vários
  arquivos de preferência, identificados por nome e especificados no
  primeiro parâmetro.
- `getPreferences()` — use esse método se precisar de apenas um arquivo
  de preferência para a Activity. Como esse será o único arquivo de
  preferências para a Activity, o nome não é fornecido.

Para gravar valores:

- Chame `edit()` para obter um SharedPreferences.Editor.
- Adicione valores com métodos como `putBoolean()` e `putString()`.
- Confirme os novos valores com `commit()`

Para ler valores, use métodos de `SharedPreferences` como `getBoolean()`
   e `getString()`.

Exemplo:

```
public class Calc extends Activity {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
       super.onCreate(state);
       . . .

       // Restore preferences
       SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
       boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false);
       setSilent(silent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
       super.onStop();

      // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
      // All objects are from android.context.Context
      SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
      editor.putBoolean("silentMode", mSilentMode);

      // Commit the edits!
      editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

O mais simples, na minha opinião, é `java.util.prefs.Preferences` ([documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.prefs/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html)) que vem junto com o Java.
Uso normalmente para salvar posição e tamanho das janelas, diretório usado para abrir arquivos, ....

Obter instância (membro de cada classe):

```
// chaves para acessar cada dado
private static final String PREF_TEXTO = "ChaveTexto";
private static final String PREF_INTEIRO = "ChaveInteiro";

private final Preferences preferences = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(getClass());
```

Salvar:

```
preferences.put(PREF_TEXTO, texto);
preferences.putInt(PREF_INTEIRO, numero);
```

Recuperar:

```
texto = prefrences.get(PREF_TEXTO, "valoe inicial");
numero = preferences.getInt(PREF_INTEIRO, 0);
```

Além do `userNode`, que vale para um determinado usuário, existe o `systemNode` que vale para todos os usuários.